# Поиск строк одного файла во втором с выводом. C++

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, файлы, вывод

Нужно:

> взять из файла #2 считать строки и найти в файле #1 строку которая
>   вмещает все до пробела.

Все по синтаксису, но где-то ошибся, ибо не выводит ничего (все библиотеки подключены).

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    char buffer[1024];
    vector<string> mails;

    ifstream input;
    input.open("1.txt");
    ifstream inpt;
    inpt.open("2.txt");
    {
        while (getline(inpt, line, ' '))
            mails.push_back(line);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < mails.size(); i++)
        {
            const char* gg = mails[i].c_str();
            while (input.getline(buffer, 1024)) 
            {
                if (strstr(buffer, gg))
                    cout << buffer << strstr(buffer, " ") << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Для этого есть отладчик.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strstr(buffer, gg))
    cout << buffer << strstr(buffer, " ") << endl;
```

если ничего не выводит `cout` это означает, что в буффере нет такой строки `gg`, или же у вас файлы пусты